# How to consume jwt token in asp.net core web api for reading only user info without any validation

Tags: asp.net, authentication, jwt, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a simple requirement to read the token in asp.net core web api for every request and read the sub part of token which has UserID. Token validation will be done by a third party rest api call which will tell if token is valid or not. No validation logic should exist in my api.

Unfortunately all the articles I have read, they are validating the token, which I don't want in my case.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following extension method to get userID from `HttpContext`. Use [ClaimType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.claims.claimtypes(v=vs.110).aspx) which contains userID value.

```
public static int GetUserID(this Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext context){
            var claimsIdentity = context.User;
            var claim = claimsIdentity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(cl => cl.Type == ClaimTypes.YOUR_CLAIM_TYPE);            
            return Convert.ToInt32(claim.Value);
        }
```

Usage in your controller methods:

```
var userID = HttpContext.GetUserID();
```